# Range value search in elastic search, not returning results

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a problem. 
I have tried to make plenty of queries and none have returned any documents.

My data format is something like:

```
{
    "_index": "orders",
    "_type": "order",
    "_id": "AVad66hjiOD-asNwVILB",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "document": {
        "orderID": "1337",
        "sku": "awesomeSku",
        "customerID": "7331",
        "productID": "20490859",
        "variantID": "97920239",
        "createTime": "2016-07-13T13:23:19Z",
        "retailPrice": "10000",
        "costPrice": "10000",
        "new": 123
      }
    }
  }
```

My query:

```
{
"query": { 
"bool": {
  "filter": [ 
    { "range": { "new": { "gte": "20" } } } 
  ]
}
  }
}
```

I just want to start somewhere simply and find all documents which has the attribute "new" with a value above 20.
Any feedback would be awesome.

Edit:

Data formart in ES:

```
{
 "orders": {
"mappings": {
  "order": {
    "properties": {
      "document": {
        "properties": {
          "costPrice": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "createTime": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "customerID": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "new": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "orderID": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "productID": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "retailPrice": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "sku": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "variantID": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  }
 }
 }
```

Comment: can you update your question with the mapping you get from `curl -XGET localhost:orders/_mapping/order` ? Your `new` field might be mapped as a string instead of a number and the string "20" > "123", hence why you get no results.

Comment: It is: "new":{"type":"long"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your query like this on the `document.new` field since all your fields are nested into the top-level `document` section:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "document.new": {
              "gte": 20
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I should go to sleep now.
So stupid of me :) 
But once again thanks.

Comment: No worries, sometimes a second pair of eyes helps. Glad we figured it out ;-)